# JSF conditional CSS issue for h:column

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I have dataTable with 8 cols. 
On 7th col I wanted specific css depends on condition.
So I added columnClasses attribute on datatable. As you can see on 7th column I have addded condition.

```html
<h:dataTable id="summaryDataTable"
  width="930"
  var="report"
  cellpadding="0px"
  columnClasses="col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, #{ report.device.seId == 'ERROR' ? 'col7diff' : 'col7'},col8">
```

1.Now issue is that condition is not getting executed properly and all 7th coloumns getting
'col7' as CSS. Even I tried with diffrent conditional statements. 
2. Also there is no attribute on `<h:column>` where i can add condition for CSS

Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: You cannot use the 'var' (report in your case) in EL in the columnClasses attribute. It is not available when the columnClasses are evaluated. Think of it... Which row should define the class for the column? The first one? The last one? It is a columnClass, not a cell/rowClass

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje . I got u r point. So isnt there any way to apply specific CSS to particular cell since i dont think <h:column> has any attribute for same.